# Yii - sorting by another table

Tags: php, yii

I'm using Yii framework and have trouble with a query as i'm new to it.

I have two tables in my database:

users:
id, username, password, fullname

friends
id, user_id, friend_id

I declared the relationships and get the user's friends by using:

```
$userFriends = $user->userfriend();
```

My problem is that I want to get the list of friends ordered by the "fullname" column in the users table.

How can I achieve that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When declaring your relation, you can specify additional options http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#relational-query-options

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'friends'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'User', 'friends(user_id,friend_id)',
                        'order'=>'fullname ASC')
    );
}
```